# Python: XOR hex values in strings

Tags: python, string, xor

Im new to python and I have (maybe) a dumb question.

I have to XOR two value. currently my values look like this:

v1 =

```
<class 'str'>
2dbdd2157b5a10ba61838a462fc7754f7cb712d6
```

v2 =

```
<class 'str'>
5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8
```

but the thing is, i need to XOR the actual HEX value instead of the ascii value of the given character in the string.

so for example:

the first byte in the first string is `s1 = 2d`, in the second string `s2 = 5b`

```
def sxor(s1,s2):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in zip(s1,s2))
```

this will not work, because it gives back the ASCII value of each character (then XOR them), which is obviously differs from the actual hex value.

Comment: Convert the hex to integers, xor the integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is converting the characters to their *ASCII codepoints*, not to integer values.

You can convert them using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) and [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) instead:

```
return ''.join(format(int(a, 16) ^ int(b, 16), 'x') for a,b in zip(s1,s2))
```

`int(string, 16)` interprets the input string as a hexadecimal value. `format(integer, 'x')` outputs a hexadecimal string for the given integer.

You can do this without `zip()` by just taking the whole strings as one big integer number:

```
return '{1:0{0}x}'.format(len(s1), int(s1, 16) ^ int(s2, 16))
```

To make sure leading `0` characters are not lost, the above uses `str.format()` to format the resulting integer to the right length of zero-padded hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the strings into int's then xor the ints:

```
def sxor(s1,s2):
    i1 = int(s1, 16)
    i2 = int(s2, 16)
    # do you want the result as an int or as another string?
    return hex(i1 ^ i2)
```

Comment: This produces a `0x` at the start and can actually produce a *shorter hex value* as leading `0` characters are lost.

Comment: Good point, I like your much better use of the format() function

Answer (score 0):

Works with python3:

```
_HAS_NUMPY = False
try:
    import numpy
    _HAS_NUMPY = True
except:
    pass

def my_xor(s1, s2):
    if _HAS_NUMPY:
        b1 = numpy.fromstring(s1, dtype="uint8")
        b2 = numpy.fromstring(s2, dtype="uint8")
        return (b1 ^ b2).tostring()

    result = bytearray(s1)
    for i, b in enumerate(s2):
        result[i] ^= b
    return result
```